# How to install manimgl on Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, manim

I wanted to use `manimgl` on Google Colab but the simple `!pip install manimgl` doesn't seem to work. I looked at several solutions. In particular:

- [ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.](https://github.com/doccano/doccano/issues/969)
- [Crear Animaciones usando Manim en Google Colab](https://gist.github.com/Macorreag/abfc02b99a751431d8793e9c5506ef49)

Would you have a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I found a relatively simple way to do it. Actually there is a lib called `jupyter-manim` that works pretty well with a few tweaks. Here is what I did:

```
!apt-get install -qq pkg-config libcairo2-dev 
!pip3 install jupyter-manim --quiet
!sudo apt-get -qq update
!sudo apt-get install -qq texlive-full
```

The `-qq` is simply not to get prompts output.

FYI, the whole installation is a little long (about 5 min).

Then, you should be able to run:

```
import jupyter_manim
from manimlib.imports import *
import statistics

%%manim OpeningScene --base64
class OpeningScene(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        first_line = TextMobject("Data Structures and Algorithms")
        second_line = TextMobject("Time Complexity and Big O Notation")
        self.play(Write(first_line))
        self.wait(2)
        self.play(Transform(first_line, second_line))
        self.wait(3)
        self.play(FadeOut(first_line))
```

I got inspired from this notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KDPi9Im-dfknrUokBpSwEM6Z710JF6Wc?usp=sharing#scrollTo=9BpcNKiWZeu-